# PDO::FETCH_ASSOC to Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, pdo, textfield

I need to fetch data from an associative array (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
and put it in 3 empty textfields below.
Can anyone help me with some code. 
Thanks in advance.

Tried the example below, no luck:

```
$("#input-full-name").val(sport.values.full_name);
$("#input-short-name").val(sport.values.short_name);
$("#input-abb-name").val(sport.values.abbreviation);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're confusing server-side and client-side actions.
*PDO* runs on the server side and communicates with the database-server.
*JavaScript* (in this case jQuery) runs on the client side and operates on the DOM.
*AJAX* is kind of a connection between those two.

So if you want to populate input-fields with some values from the database, you can either do it on the server side:

```
<?php
//run query, fetch array and store it in $sport
?>

<input type="text" name="full_name" value="<?php echo $sport['full-name']; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="short_name" value="<?php echo $sport['short-name']; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="abbreviation" value="<?php echo $sport['abb-name']; ?>" />
```

Or you can do it on the client-side (e.g. if the user clicks a link/button/whatever):

```
<?php
//this is the script you make an AJAX-request to, e.g. get_data.php

//run query, fetch array and store it in $sport

echo json_encode($sport); //echo the array in JSON-format
```

This is the page served to the user:

```
...
  <input type="text" name="full_name" id="input-full-name" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="short_name" id="input-short-name" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="abbreviation" id="input-abb-name" value="" />
...
<button id="populate_btn">Populate Data</button>

<scrip>
  $('#populate_btn').click(functiion(){
    $.post('get_data.php', {}, function(sport) {
       //sport now contains the json-array
       $.each(sport, function(key, value) {
         $('#input-'+key).val(value);
       });
    });
  });
</script>
```

It's a very basic example, but I hope you get the idea. Also note that the given AJAX example only works if the keys of the array match the `id`-attributes of the input-fields in some kind, e.g.: `$sport['full-name'] and <input id="input-full-name" />`. This makes it much easier to work with it.